# How to authorize an HTTP POST request to execute dataflow template with REST API

Tags: node.js, rest, google-cloud-platform, authorization, dataflow

I am trying to execute the Cloud Bigtable to Cloud Storage SequenceFile template via REST API in a NodeJS backend server.

I am using axios 0.17.1 to send the request and I'm getting 401 status. 
I tried to follow the google documentation however I couldn't figure out how to authorize an HTTP request to run a dataflow template. 
I want to be authenticated as a service account and I successfully generated and dowloaded the json file containing the private key.
Can anyone help me by showing an example of sending HTTP POST request to https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/templates:launch?gcsPath=gs://dataflow-templates/latest/

Comment: I'm working on the same thing right now.  The docs are not very helpful regarding doing this via HTTP.  I think you can generate a JWT from the service account credentials, exchange the JWT for an access token, and then use that to make the request. I'm getting a 403, but it may be a permissions error.  Give this a try: https://gist.github.com/adrice727/1199e1e3df87018058926fec6447e583

Comment: Update: Can confirm that the above works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a `jwt` from your service account credentials.  The jwt can be exchanged for an access token which can then be used to make the request to execute the Dataflow job.  Complete example:

```
import axios from "axios";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import mem from "mem";
import fs from "fs";

const loadServiceAccount = mem(function(){
    // This is a string containing service account credentials
    const serviceAccountJson = process.env.GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS;
    if (!serviceAccountJson) {
      throw new Error("Missing GCP Credentials");
    }
})

const loadCredentials = mem(function() {

  loadServiceAccount();

  const credentials = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("key.json").toString());

  return {
    projectId: credentials.project_id,
    privateKeyId: credentials.private_key_id,
    privateKey: credentials.private_key,
    clientEmail: credentials.client_email,
  };
});

interface ProjectCredentials {
  projectId: string;
  privateKeyId: string;
  privateKey: string;
  clientEmail: string;
}

function generateJWT(params: ProjectCredentials) {
  const scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform";
  const authUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
  const issued = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
  const expires = issued + 60;

  const payload = {
    iss: params.clientEmail,
    sub: params.clientEmail,
    aud: authUrl,
    iat: issued,
    exp: expires,
    scope: scope,
  };

  const options = {
    keyid: params.privateKeyId,
    algorithm: "RS256",
  };

  return jwt.sign(payload, params.privateKey, options);
}

async function getAccessToken(credentials: ProjectCredentials): Promise<string> {
  const jwt = generateJWT(credentials);
  const authUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
  const params = {
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    assertion: jwt,
  };
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(authUrl, params);
    return response.data.access_token;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to get access token", error);
    throw error;
  }
}

function buildTemplateParams(projectId: string, table: string) {
  return {
    jobName: `[job-name]`,
    parameters: {
      bigtableProjectId: projectId,
      bigtableInstanceId: "[table-instance]",
      bigtableTableId: table,
      outputDirectory: `[gs://your-instance]`,
      filenamePrefix: `${table}-`,
    },
    environment: {
      zone: "us-west1-a" // omit or define your own,
      tempLocation: `[gs://your-instance/temp]`,
    },
  };
}

async function backupTable(table: string) {
  console.info(`Executing backup template for table=${table}`);
  const credentials = loadCredentials();
  const { projectId } = credentials;
  const accessToken = await getAccessToken(credentials);
  const baseUrl = "https://dataflow.googleapis.com/v1b3/projects";
  const templatePath = "gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Cloud_Bigtable_to_GCS_Avro";
  const url = `${baseUrl}/${projectId}/templates:launch?gcsPath=${templatePath}`;
  const template = buildTemplateParams(projectId, table);
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(url, template, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}` },
    });
    console.log("GCP Response", response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to execute template for ${table}`, error.message);
  }
}

async function run() {
  await backupTable("my-table");
}

try {
  run();
} catch (err) {
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, the template requires more scopes so I added them as a single, space-delimited string.
Unfortunately, `JSON.parse()` raised an exception `Unexpected token \ in JSON at position 1` I replaced `\\n` with a space, the call to launch the template was sent but I got `400 bad request`. Would you please help me to debug the bad request?

Comment: I got the bad request because I used wrong template parameters

Comment: @MelekKaroui Answer is updated to fix the issue with credentials json.